# Kue - Error: Auth error: ERR max number of clients reached

Tags: redis, kue

I am getting an redis connection error when depolyed in APP Fog. I don't know if KUE is generating too many connections.

Here is stack

```
/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/kue-0-543205581cf47e8551d042ab06df92e1/app/node_mod
ules/redis/index.js:516
throw callback_err;
^
Error: Auth error: ERR max number of clients reached
at Command.RedisClient.do_auth.self.send_anyway as callback
at RedisClient.return_error (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/kue-0-543205581cf4
7e8551d042ab06df92e1/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:512:25)
at ReplyParser.RedisClient.init_parser (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/kue-0-5
43205581cf47e8551d042ab06df92e1/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:263:14)
at ReplyParser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
at ReplyParser.send_error (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/kue-0-543205581cf47e
8551d042ab06df92e1/app/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:296:10)
at ReplyParser.execute (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/kue-0-543205581cf47e855
1d042ab06df92e1/app/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:181:22)
at RedisClient.on_data (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/kue-0-543205581cf47e855
1d042ab06df92e1/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:488:27)
at Socket. (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/kue-0-543205581cf47e8551
d042ab06df92e1/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:82:14)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
at TCP.onread (net.js:396:14)
```

The redis server log shows it made 5 client connections. is there a way to reduce the no of connections

Thanks

Comment: is this supposed to be your production environment ?

Comment: I think I have the same problem as   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568943/trouble-connecting-to-redis-to-go-with-with-multiple-worker-kues                             what is the workaround for this